# LiftWeb not Covariant Type In Cell

Tags: scala, lift

I am dealing with [Cell](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.util.Cell) and I have a problem because they are not covariant. Here is what I want to do:

```
import net.liftweb.util.Cell

trait A {}
class AA extends A {}

trait T{
  val cell:Cell[A]
}

class U extends T{
  val cell:Cell[AA] = //implementation
}
```

I have an error because `AA` is a descendent of `A` but not equal to `A`.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Actually, you're mistaken.  Your error is "error: overriding value cell in trait T of type Cell[AA]; method cell needs to be a stable, immutable value: def cell:Cell[AA]".</s>

Now, while I might suggest having T take a type parameter V <: A and then having the cell() function return a Cell[V], the real problem here is not even really related to generics.  In T, your 'cell' is a data member.  In U, 'cell' is a function.  The compiler simply wants you to choose one (and the one that works and makes sense is for it to be a function in both places, so... just change that "val cell" to "def cell" and give one of those 'cell' definitions an implementation, and you're fine).

**Update** (now that the question has been fixed):

Alright, so, as suggested in my original answer, you'll want trait T to take a type parameter in order to solve this, like so:

```
trait A {}
class AA extends A {}

trait T[V <: A]{
  val cell:Cell[V]
}

class U(inCell: Cell[AA]) extends {val cell = inCell} with T[AA]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, however what you point out is just a typo when I "translated" my problem, I will edit my question to clarify my point.

Comment: I tested your solution and I still have a problem: first I have the following error "You may wish to define V as -V instead", then when I insert the minus I have "contravariant type V occurs in invariant position in type => net.liftweb.util.Cell[V] of value cell". 
So it seems like the trick doesn't hold.

Comment: Well, if you want the Scala covariance modifier, it's '+' (not '-').  It might be worth trying that.  I don't have actually have Lift (and I'm not having an easy time in trying to acquire it), but... if adding doing V -> +V doesn't fix it... I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

1. From scaladoc definition `trait Cell [T] extends Dependent`, [Cell](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.util.Cell) is **not** covariant
2. `val` can override parameterless method, but not vice versa.
3. Either class `U` should be abstract or `cell` function defined.

If `Cell` is covariant, with these changes your example should work.

```
scala> trait Cell[+T]
defined trait Cell

scala> trait A
defined trait A

scala> class AA extends A
defined class AA

scala> trait T { def cell: Cell[A] }
defined trait T

scala> class U extends T { override def val: Cell[AA] = new Cell[AA] {} }
defined class U
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, however I did a few mistakes when creating my question. I edited it in consequence. 
In your answer, when you type `trait Cell[+T]`, is this an implementation of lift cells or is this a totally new trait without any predecessor? Because I need the properties of `Cell`

Comment: @ChrisJamesC, it's brand new covariant `Cell`; in lift implementation `Cell` has invariant type parameter. See Destin's answer, that's probably what you want.